# Website recommendations

Tags: discussion, migration

A site which would be an obvious migration target for us, [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations?referrer=But9unTMknHWgagw76fBpg2), is barely over 50% committed.

Oddly, in the list of six other Stack Exchange sites where the committers are also active, Web Apps is not listed. That seems wrong.

So, let us unburden ourselves of the neverending trickle of questions asking for a web site recommendation and get this one off of the ground.

Comment: Quite ironic indeed!

Comment: [The proposal has been closed.](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/22174)

Comment: Well, that's a bummer.

Comment: Maybe we can use some of the justification here for some of the request questions we get. In other words, take away "is there a site that..." and see what you're left with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the need for this proposal, or its benefit to WA. Recommendations of Web *Applications* are already on topic at Software Recommendations.

- [Are web service recommendations off-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45), written by a SR mod.
- [No to Websites; Yes to Webapps](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/219), a detailed analysis of distinction between websites (which are off-topic at SR) and  webapps (which are on topic).

Most of recommendation questions we get are about web apps (not surprisingly). These can be carefully directed to SR: for example

> Your question may be on topic at Software Recommendations if you can rewrite it so that it meets their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Questions about other kinds of websites are not common, and can be simply closed as *not about Web Applications*, like any other blatantly off-topic question. (Which would be even simpler [if we had a generic OT close reason](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3847)).

Comment: Perhaps we need to adjust the text of our "recommendation" off-topic reason.

Answer (score -3):

The proposal has been restarted: [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations?referrer=AQx0849qiZ8aDHio0gR48w2)

Comment: The new proposal seeks to exclude Web applications. It's focus is on "classic" Web sites. I am not confident it will gain enough traction.