# Please update the "recommendation" custom off-topic reason to include guidance to Software Recs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

Among our current custom off-topic Close reasons is one for questions asking for recommendations. It currently reads:

> Application/website recommendations are off-topic and out of scope. It is better instead to use a particular web app or website and ask for help in any issues you have with it specifically.

However, Web App (but not Web Site) recommendations *are* on-topic at Software Recommendations.<sup>1</sup> Since that site is now out of beta, I think we should add some extra guidance to that close reason that it may be a good place for the Asker's question (even if we don't add SoftwareRecs as a migration path).

This would be similar to two of the close-as-off-topic reasons on Stack Overflow:

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).
>
> Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

---

Therefore, I propose that the language for the "recommendation" close reason be changed to:

> Questions asking for us to **recommend or find a Web Application** are off-topic and out of scope, as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. However, your question *may* be on topic at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) if you can rewrite it so that it meets their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3944/354)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had added this as a close reason. <strike>I am waiting for another moderator to approve the change before it goes live.</strike>

[image: Close Reasons]